# In R3 Corda I don't know to start the web server port?

Tags: corda

In R3 Corda all the nodes are up and running fine.But I don't know to start the web server port?

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to run a separate web server to connect to a node, not the deprecated in-process webserver. Check out this post for some more information - [Moving to Spring webserver from internal webserver](https://medium.com/corda/spring-cleaning-migrating-your-cordapp-away-from-the-deprecated-corda-jetty-web-server-9d618371fc92).

Answer (score 0):

You have to run spring boot server.

https://docs.corda.net/tutorial-cordapp.html#id2

```
Unix/Mac OSX: ./gradlew runPartyXServer
Windows: gradlew.bat runPartyXServer
```